# Transform Rows into Columns Table Data (Infinity Plugin)

Tags: grafana, datasource, transformation

I'm trying to transform data using the Infinity plugin as the main datasource in Grafana version 9.1.7.

API endpoint used:
https://9498199887151372.hostedstatus.com/1.0/status/5d849b1c02e65b3ec45369d4

[image]

Current table view is as follows:
[image]

We would like to represent the data as follows:

```
name (as column 1).             | status (as column 2)
unique values from the column 2 | Operational (as status)
```

Please find the current transformation settings set up and highly appreciate if you could advise which particular transformations can be used in this case.

Comment: What is in your Parsing configuration? [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUa2I.png) seems to produce result similar to the one you are expecting, but I have doubts about repetition of multiple rows for different containers.

Comment: thanks, wondering if we could limit the "name|status" view to the particular section under "name": "Australian Grid", for example?

Comment: You mean you want selector like `result.status[name="Australian Grid"].containers`?

Comment: Perfect, that worked great, thanks a lot! Also trying to parse the https://status.aws.amazon.com/rss/all.rss RSS feed as suggested in the native plugin discussions - https://github.com/yesoreyeram/grafana-infinity-datasource/discussions/244. It doesn't look like it work if we specify the "rss.channel[0].item" value as Rows/Root but it works if set the "rss.channel", thus this way looks like it can be set only for the specific service.